# ColdFusion/Java - "The build method was not found"

Tags: java, coldfusion

We are using some org.apache classes as part of implementing WS Security for a webservice.

```
variables.paths = arrayNew(1);
variables.paths[1] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "lib\wss4j-1.5.8.jar";
variables.paths[2] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "lib\xmlsec-1.4.2.jar";
variables.loader = createObject("component","lib.javaloader.JavaLoader").init(loadPaths=variables.paths,loadColdFusionClassPath=true);
variables.WSConstantsObj = loader.create("org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants");
variables.messageClass = loader.create("org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecUsernameToken");
variables.secHeaderClass = loader.create("org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecHeader");
```

The following code:

```
<cfset var msg = getMessage()>
```

produces:

[image]

The following code:

```
<cfset var secHeader = getSecHeader()>
```

produces:

[image]

The following code:

```
<cfset var env = soapEnv.getDocumentElement()>
```

produces:

[image]

```
env.getOwnerDocument()
```

produces a huge structure (too big to include here), which you can [view here](http://www.china-buy.com/tga/index.cfm?viewDump).

However, the following code:

```
<cfset e = msg.build(env.GetOwnerDocument(),secHeader)>
```

throws the error:

```
 The build method was not found.
Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the build method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.
```

However the Build() method certainly exists, as per the yellow highlight in the first screenshot.

The error message talks about "...use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity". If this were the problem, how would I apply this solution?

Comment: All that red makes my eyes bleed :(

Comment: You've cfdumped everything except for what env.GetOwnerDocument() actually returns. Could you try that?  If for some reason it is returning NULL or something unexpected it could certainly cause a problem

Comment: wait... are you using a capital G in env.GetOwnerDocument()?

Comment: Yeah, I was but changing it to lowercase didn't make a difference. I dumped out env.GetOwnerDocument() and it's a huge nested structure with about 4 levels of extended methods.

Comment: See this dump at http://www.china-buy.com/tga/index.cfm?viewDump

Comment: So, interestingly, even though the dump of env shows that getOwnerDocument() return an object of type org.w3c.dom.Document what you are getting when you call it is a org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl, which does not seem to extend or implement org.w3c.dom.Document.  Since build() is expecting a org.w3c.dom.Document I think that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Can you provide a dump of env like you did with getOwnerDocument()?

Comment: Wait, I take it back. org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl *does* implement org.w3c.dom.Document. So I'm not sure what to tell you at this point.

Comment: My guess would be that one of your JARs contains the interface class es for org.w3c.dom.Document or something else that ColdFusion also has in it's JARs. You can often wind up with the situation where different classloaders cload up the same class definitions form different places and even though your classes are of the right type, the definitions have some from different places and are classed as different classes. Try turning off the loadColdFusionClassPath option. You'll have to copy some of the JARs from CF's /lib folder, but you'll avoid some of the classloading strangeness that can occur

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway guys. Barnyr, would you happen to know which CF jars I'd be missing? I've got a feeling you're right about that. BTW, I did turn off the loadColdFusionClassPath option but it made no difference.

Comment: do the basic examples here work at all for you? https://github.com/anthony-id/cfWSAuthenticator

Comment: I set mine up like that, with the only difference being that I loaded the additional jars with javaloader. The errors I've been discussing here prevent me from completing the deal with the example.

Comment: Odd, I was just using the example files (sans javaloader) without trouble.  The issues I saw which resulted in the same error, were calling methods in the wrong order, or skipping a method. I was altering the code to add a timestamp.  It looks like you skipped some code or didn't mention it here, msg.setUserInfo, nonce, created, etc.  All those there and in the right order right?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that "build()" doesn't exist but that your signature is incorrect. The 2 arguments for the build method are:

```
env.GetOwnerDocument(),secHeader
```

We know that that secHeader is of the class

```
org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecHeader
```

Because your cfdump indicates as much.

That likely means that "env.GetOwnerDocument" is not returning an object of the class

```
org.w3c.dom.Document
```

It may be returning an error or a primitive or another class. Instantiate envGetOwnerDocumet() and dump that out and check the class. I think it is screwing up the method signature. That's my best guess anyway.

Comment: I missed the additional comments... looks like Barnyr and jason D have already covered this for you. sorry :)

Comment: Thanks Mark. Jason responded that org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl does implement org.w3c.dom.Document. The dump of envGetOwnerDocument() I provided is provided here: http://www.china-buy.com/tga/index.cfm?viewDump

Comment: Yeah I saw that after I had written my comment. I wonder if it's implemented corrrectly? It still seems to me to be the most likely candidate. Can you instantiate an org.w3c.dom.Document class directly and use it instead? or do you have to have the xerces class?